# Context menu Item Listener

Tags: android

I have made a context menu but I cant get the itemListener to work because I cant use switch-case for the selected title(since it works only for Integer,Not string).

I want to do something upon clicking the item. Although I can do it with (IF statement).

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview);
        View view=findViewById(R.id.myView);
        registerForContextMenu(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");  
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Item 1");  
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Item 2");  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case 0: Toast.makeText(this, "Item selected 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;
        case 1: Toast.makeText(this, "Item selected 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;
        default:

    }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting both the IDs for your options to the same thing, so this won't work. The second argument in the [`add()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method is supposed to be a unique ID to allow you to determine the option clicked later on. Try something like:

```
//Class level variables
static int OPTION_ONE = 1;
static int OPTION_TWO = 2;

//Adding the options
menu.add(0, OPTION_ONE, 0, "Item 1");  
menu.add(0, OPTION_TWO, 0, "Item 2"); 

//Determining which one was clicked
switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case OPTION_ONE: 
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item selected 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        break;
    case OPTION_TWO: 
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item selected 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        break;
    default:
```